# Determine size of Stateflow Subchart

Tags: matlab, size, simulink, stateflow

I am writing a Model Advisor check right now and I need to know the size of a subcharted Stateflow State or Box. But the "Stateflow.State" and "Stateflow.Box" objects only have a "Position" attribute, which gives their position inside their parent elements. I need to know the size of the subchart itself (where their contents reside). How can I get this size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally asked the MathWorks support for a solution and got this answer:

> [...] there is currently no API functionality to retrieve the size of the subchart in the subchart subviewer. Unfortunately there are no workarounds to access this information currently.

*Update:* I recently learned about the undocumented `sf` API. It is possible to get information about the subchart with it. Therefore you need to get the ID of the State whos dimensions are needed. Here is an example:

```
r = sfroot;
s = r.find('-isa', 'Stateflow.State', '-and', 'IsSubchart', 1);
sf('get', s(1).id, '.subviewS.pos')
```

This does the following:

1. Store the `Simulink.Root` object in `r`.
2. Find all subcharted States and store them in `s`. You might need to refine the search to detect the exact State you need.
3. Use the `sf` API to retrieve the position `.pos` of the first Subchart, which is represented by `.subviewS`

There is plenty of information about each of the Stateflow objects. To investigate further, you just need to find the appropriate object (using `r.find()`) and use `sf('get', <object>.id)`. This lists all available information about the Stateflow object `<object>`.

Answer (score 0):

The "Position" attribute is the absolute position of "Stateflow.State" inside the Chart.Here is an example:

```
___________________
|AA               |
|___________      |
||BB       |      |
||_________|      |
-------------------

AA = r.find('-isa', 'Stateflow.State', 'Name', 'AA').Position

AA = 330.0924  542.7458  157.4576   94.6164

BB = r.find('-isa', 'Stateflow.State', 'Name', 'BB').Position

BB = 334.5304  571.1490  115.7404   62.6628
```

Comment: You're right. But what I need is the size of AA, if it is subcharted. Then BB's position is the absolute position inside the Stateflow.State AA and not the chart. And I then need the size (not necessarily the position) of AA as you have drawn it.

Comment: The attribute "Position" is consist of the coordinate of the upper - left corner , the width and  height of  the state.